# Why does string cheese taste different when pulled apart than when bitten?

Tags: flavor, cheese

I enjoy string cheese, and there's definite tactile enjoyment in pulling it apart into thin strands and then eating them. I've found, however, that the taste when I pull it apart is clearly different from the taste when I just bite off a hunk; the thin strands taste saltier than the bulk cheese, which in contrast is somewhat bland.

Why is there a difference in flavor when the basic material is exactly the same?

Answer (score 2):

All your doing by seperating it into strands is exposing more surface area. So when you put it in your mouth you experience a sudden "big" taste sensation. If you chew it your exposure to the taste doesn't come in such a big "rush".